# How to eliminate repeated values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two CSVs. One is about donations for politicians: each line is a donation and each line has the name of the donor company and the federal registration number of that company (CPF_CNPJ_doador - unique for each company in the country)

```
CPF_CNPJ_doador Nome_doador                               Valor
73668675000187  CWVGRAFICA EDITORA E BAZAR EIRELI LTDA ME 1000,00

83647909000163  CARBONIFERA CRICIUMA S/A 1750,00

10731057000114  HAROLDO AZEVEDO CONSTRUÇÕES LTDA 100,00
...
```

The other CSV has companies that have environmental irregularities. You have several data, including the company name and the federal registration number of that company (CPF_CNPJ - unique for each company in the country).
But a company may appear more than once in this CSV - it may have multiple affiliates with irregularities for example

```
Nome_Razao_Social   CPF_CNPJ
Carajas Madeiras Industria e Comercio Ltda - Me 02579504000214
Carbo Gás Ltda  03828695000435
Carbomil Química S/A    07645062000108
Carbomil Química S/A    07645062000108
...
```

I made a pandas merge (Python 3) of these two CSVs:

```
ibama_doadores = pd.merge(eleitos_d_doadores, ibama, left_on = 'CPF_CNPJ_doador', right_on = 'CPF_CNPJ')
```

The problem is that the command looks for the result matches in both CSVs, but it repeats the lines whenever the second CSV the CPF_CNPJ_doador appears more than once:

```
CPF_CNPJ_doador Nome_doador_originario
7645062000108.0 CARBOMIL QUIMICA S A
7645062000108.0 CARBOMIL QUIMICA S A
7645062000108.0 CARBOMIL QUIMICA S A
...
```

Please, is there a merge type that eliminates repeated values? If the item searched in the second database is repeated

Comment: There is problem `CPF_CNPJ_doador`  or `CPF_CNPJ` are duplicated, or both.

Comment: Both can be duplicated in CSVs (a politician can receive donations from the same company on different dates, for example).

Comment: But I want to get all the lines of donations, even if they are from lines with duplicate companies. But they have to exist in the second CSV

Comment: The problem is that if the company is quoted in the second CSV more than once, the donation is doubled, then in the wrong way

Comment: OK, if `CPF_CNPJ_doador` first value is `07645062000108` then what is desired output? Do you want match first duplicated values in one column to first duplicated value in second df column?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No, I imagine a command to: find the X number of the first database in the second database then record that match. And then save all occurrences of the number X of the first base. Something like

Comment: I do not know if that exists. Maybe it's best to just delete the same lines in the original merge file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one possible solution is remove duplicates in both DataFrames:

```
ibama_doadores = pd.merge(eleitos_d_doadores.drop_duplicates('CPF_CNPJ_doador'), 
                          ibama.drop_duplicates('CPF_CNPJ'), 
                          left_on = 'CPF_CNPJ_doador',
                          right_on = 'CPF_CNPJ')
```

Or create new columns for count duplicates and add this column for join:

```
eleitos_d_doadores['g'] = eleitos_d_doadores.groupby('CPF_CNPJ_doador').cumcount()
ibama['g'] = ibama.groupby('CPF_CNPJ').cumcount()

ibama_doadores = pd.merge(eleitos_d_doadores, 
                          ibama, 
                          left_on = ['CPF_CNPJ_doador','g'],
                          right_on = ['CPF_CNPJ','g']).drop('g', 1)
```

Samples:

```
eleitos_d_doadores = pd.DataFrame({
    'CPF_CNPJ_doador': ['a','b','c','c','a'],
    'B': list(range(1,6))
})

ibama = pd.DataFrame({
    'CPF_CNPJ': ['a','b','a','a','c'],
    'C': list(range(5))
})

ibama_doadores = pd.merge(eleitos_d_doadores.drop_duplicates('CPF_CNPJ_doador'), 
                          ibama.drop_duplicates('CPF_CNPJ'), 
                          left_on = 'CPF_CNPJ_doador',
                          right_on = 'CPF_CNPJ')
print (ibama_doadores)
   B CPF_CNPJ_doador  C CPF_CNPJ
0  1               a  0        a
1  2               b  1        b
2  3               c  4        c
```

---

```
eleitos_d_doadores['g'] = eleitos_d_doadores.groupby('CPF_CNPJ_doador').cumcount()
ibama['g'] = ibama.groupby('CPF_CNPJ').cumcount()

ibama_doadores = pd.merge(eleitos_d_doadores, 
                          ibama, 
                          left_on = ['CPF_CNPJ_doador','g'],
                          right_on = ['CPF_CNPJ','g']).drop('g', 1)

print (ibama_doadores)
   B CPF_CNPJ_doador  C CPF_CNPJ
0  1               a  0        a
1  2               b  1        b
2  3               c  4        c
3  5               a  2        a
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I deleted only the duplicate lines from the second CSV (some columns I've changed the name, the content is the same):

Comment: ibama_doadores_orig= pd.merge(eleitos_d_doadores, ibama.drop_duplicates('CPF_CNPJ_limpo'), left_on='CPF_CNPJ_doador_originario', right_on='CPF_CNPJ_limpo', how = 'left')

Comment: Hmmm, and no duplicates yet?

Comment: And then I deleted null results:

Comment: ibama_doadores_orig = ibama_doadores_orig[pd.notnull(ibama_doadores_orig['CPF_CNPJ_limpo'])]

Comment: From the first CSV I want to have duplicate results, as I said. Because they are business gifts, they can be repeated on different dates. I'm checking in the Excel PivotTable, it looks like it worked.